# How to pad a string with blanks if desired length isn't long enough?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I am creating a random access file that stores a player's name, rank, and skill, and I'm making it so that if you type in a player's name that is longer than 26, it's cut out at 26, and if it is shorter than 26, I want to pad it with blanks.

I figured out the subString to make sure only the first 26 get chosen, but I was wondering what you guys would suggest to make sure I have 26 padded blanks if I didn't put any value. This is only a snippet of my code, if you would like me to add more, I will.

```
public static String PlayerNameMethod (RandomAccessFile store){
    try{
        String PlayerName = input.next();
        store.writeUTF(PlayerName);
        if (PlayerName.length()> 26){
            PlayerName.substring(0,26);
            System.out.print("The Player Name is" + PlayerName);
        }

        if (PlayerName.length()< 26){
            //PART I CANT FIGURE OUT
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways in which you can do that - the most straightforward one being a loop in which you add spaces until the string is long enough.

But one way which has very short code and uses built in functions is the `String.format` function:

```
PlayerName = String.format("%-26s", PlayerName);
```

---

Note that you have some problems in the rest of your code. The line:

```
PlayerName.substring(0,26);
```

doesn't do anything. Strings are *immutable*, meaning that functions that change a string always return the new string - they don't modify the original one.

So that line should be:

```
PlayerName = PlayerName.substring(0,26);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @Erwin has mentioned is the most concise. 
However if you want to do it yourself this is what you would need to do.

```
   if (PlayerName.length() < 26)
    {
        StringBuilder paddedName = new StringBuilder(PlayerName);
        for (int i = 0; i < 26 - PlayerName.length(); i++)
        {
            paddedName.append(" ");
        }
        PlayerName = paddedName.toString();
    }
```

Note: java convention dictates that you should have variable names starting with a lower case. In your case `playerName`

Comment: OP wants blanks not zeros. And instead of the `for` loop and extra variables you can just do `while (paddedName.length() < 26) paddedName.append (' ');`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, had intended to replace the zero.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string of length=26-PlayerName.length() with each character as blank and append it to the PlayerName